# How safe is saving your mysqli connection as a session in php

Tags: php, mysql, session

I would like to know the pros and cons, or if it is really a bad practice.

Comment: Why would you even want to do it?

Comment: Well, you CAN save link connection but first of all - it have a resource type. Second, you your MySQL haven't permanent connection - this link will be completely useless.

Comment: actually i didn't, i'm just reading a code where it was done and i had the same reaction, So i chose to inquire, maybe there's something i could learn.

Comment: I suggest you create a connection file instead, and just include it where you need it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible.

First read [Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php)  mentioning in a highlighted  **Warning** :

Because session data is serialized, resource variables cannot be stored in the session.

Serialize handlers (php and php_binary) inherit register_globals limitations. Therefore, numeric index or string index contains special characters (| and !) cannot be used. Using these will end up with errors at script shutdown. php_serialize does not have such limitations. php_serialize is available from PHP 5.5.4.

You can also read about pros and cons from [here](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-using-PHP)

Comment: Nope :) php_serialize does not have such limitations. php_serialize is available from PHP 5.5.4.

Comment: So you have to update first sentence. Because it IS possible ;) Useless but possible

Comment: @AlexSlipknot Read documentation. still it's impossible.

Comment: First I suggest you to try write some example code. PHP is a extremely growing. So It DOES work with PHP7.1

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class which stores the connection details and the link object. Then create class functions which verify the connection is active or initializes it before returning the link. This would allow you to define your management object once, store it in the session and be able to call the link object anytime during the life of the session without having to manually reinitialize or rely on includes. Not 100% sure what the downsides might be, open to criticism there.

You could also probably use one of the existing php mysql wrapper classes for this: [What is the best PHP MYSQL wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727879/what-is-the-best-php-mysql-wrapper)